# HttpClient ObjectDisposedException Android

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, httpwebrequest

I am testing an HTTP Request to my API while the server is down.
It should receive an error response, but instead, it returns null and it gives me this exception:
System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed Stream.

This happens in Android only, iOS I get an error response. this is my code:

```cs
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    try
    {
        //pedido de token

        var loginInfo = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userAuth).ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        var requestToken = await client.PostAsync(URLs.url + URLs.getToken, loginInfo);
        var receiveToken = await requestToken.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

It doesn't reach the ReadAsString, throws the exception in the PostAsync.

Comment: If the server is down, you won't receive an error response. You will receive nothing at all, because the server is not there to respond to your request.

Comment: There is nothing to reach since the server is down and nothing will send a response ! So what the app is really doing is trying to read nothing.

Comment: I do get a response. The status code is 200 and returns an HTML page with the error in iOS. Only in Android the response is null.

Comment: If you are getting a response, then your server is not down. In your android project, go to properties -> android build, and look at what your HttpClient Implementation is. Mine is AndroidClientHandler, but it has been ages since I set that up so someone that uses this more frequently than I do will have to help you if that doesn't work.

Comment: Mine is also AndroidClientHandler. I am accessing an url "A", which isn't reachable, so it redirects me to url "B". iOS seems to be handling this with no problem, but Android is not.

Comment: What is redirecting you and where is it redirecting you to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't dispose of `HttpClient`. It is designed to be reused and handle multiple simultaneous requests.

Here's more info about how `HttpClient` works: https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/

Here is a generic implementation that I use for all HttpClient services in my Xamarin.Forms apps:

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

using Newtonsoft.Json;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace NameSpace
{
    public abstract class BaseHttpClientService
    {
        #region Constant Fields
        static readonly Lazy<JsonSerializer> _serializerHolder = new Lazy<JsonSerializer>();
        static readonly Lazy<HttpClient> _clientHolder = new Lazy<HttpClient>(() => CreateHttpClient(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)));
        #endregion

        #region Fields
        static int _networkIndicatorCount = 0;
        #endregion

        #region Events
        public static event EventHandler<string> HttpRequestFailed;
        #endregion

        #region Properties
        static HttpClient Client => _clientHolder.Value;
        static JsonSerializer Serializer => _serializerHolder.Value;
        #endregion

        #region Methods
        protected static async Task<T> GetObjectFromAPI<T>(string apiUrl)
        {
            using (var responseMessage = await GetObjectFromAPI(apiUrl).ConfigureAwait(false))
                return await DeserializeResponse<T>(responseMessage).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        protected static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetObjectFromAPI(string apiUrl)
        {
            try
            {
                UpdateActivityIndicatorStatus(true);

                return await Client.GetAsync(apiUrl).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                OnHttpRequestFailed(e.Message);
                Report(e);
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                UpdateActivityIndicatorStatus(false);
            }
        }

        protected static async Task<TResponse> PostObjectToAPI<TResponse, TRequest>(string apiUrl, TRequest requestData)
        {
            using (var responseMessage = await PostObjectToAPI(apiUrl, requestData).ConfigureAwait(false))
                return await DeserializeResponse<TResponse>(responseMessage).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        protected static Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostObjectToAPI<T>(string apiUrl, T requestData) => SendAsync(HttpMethod.Post, apiUrl, requestData);

        protected static async Task<TResponse> PutObjectToAPI<TResponse, TRequest>(string apiUrl, TRequest requestData)
        {
            using (var responseMessage = await PutObjectToAPI(apiUrl, requestData).ConfigureAwait(false))
                return await DeserializeResponse<TResponse>(responseMessage).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        protected static Task<HttpResponseMessage> PutObjectToAPI<T>(string apiUrl, T requestData) => SendAsync(HttpMethod.Put, apiUrl, requestData);

        protected static async Task<TResponse> PatchObjectToAPI<TResponse, TRequest>(string apiUrl, TRequest requestData)
        {
            using (var responseMessage = await PatchObjectToAPI(apiUrl, requestData).ConfigureAwait(false))
                return await DeserializeResponse<TResponse>(responseMessage).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        protected static Task<HttpResponseMessage> PatchObjectToAPI<T>(string apiUrl, T requestData) => SendAsync(new HttpMethod("PATCH"), apiUrl, requestData);

        protected static async Task<TResponse> DeleteObjectFromAPI<TResponse>(string apiUrl)
        {
            using (var responseMessage = await DeleteObjectFromAPI(apiUrl).ConfigureAwait(false))
                return await DeserializeResponse<TResponse>(responseMessage).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        protected static Task<HttpResponseMessage> DeleteObjectFromAPI(string apiUrl) => SendAsync<object>(HttpMethod.Delete, apiUrl);

        static HttpClient CreateHttpClient(TimeSpan timeout)
        {
            HttpClient client;
            switch (Device.RuntimePlatform)
            {
                case Device.iOS:
                case Device.Android:
                    client = new HttpClient();
                    break;
                default:
                    client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler { AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip });
                    break;
            }

            client.Timeout = timeout;
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("gzip"));

            return client;
        }

        static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync<T>(HttpMethod httpMethod, string apiUrl, T requestData = default)
        {
            using (var httpRequestMessage = await GetHttpRequestMessage(httpMethod, apiUrl, requestData).ConfigureAwait(false))
            {
                try
                {
                    UpdateActivityIndicatorStatus(true);

                    return await Client.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage).ConfigureAwait(false);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    OnHttpRequestFailed(e.Message);
                    Report(e);
                    throw;
                }
                finally
                {
                    UpdateActivityIndicatorStatus(false);
                }
            }
        }

        protected static void UpdateActivityIndicatorStatus(bool isActivityIndicatorDisplayed)
        {
            if (isActivityIndicatorDisplayed)
            {
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => Application.Current.MainPage.IsBusy = true);
                _networkIndicatorCount++;
            }
            else if (--_networkIndicatorCount <= 0)
            {
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => Application.Current.MainPage.IsBusy = false);
                _networkIndicatorCount = 0;
            }
        }

        static async ValueTask<HttpRequestMessage> GetHttpRequestMessage<T>(HttpMethod method, string apiUrl, T requestData = default)
        {
            var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(method, apiUrl);

            switch (requestData)
            {
                case T data when data.Equals(default(T)):
                    break;

                case Stream stream:
                    httpRequestMessage.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
                    httpRequestMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
                    break;

                default:
                    var stringPayload = await Task.Run(() => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestData)).ConfigureAwait(false);
                    httpRequestMessage.Content = new StringContent(stringPayload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                    break;
            }

            return httpRequestMessage;
        }

        static async Task<T> DeserializeResponse<T>(HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage)
        {
            httpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            try
            {
                using (var contentStream = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(contentStream))
                using (var json = new JsonTextReader(reader))
                {
                    if (json is null)
                        return default;

                    return await Task.Run(() => Serializer.Deserialize<T>(json)).ConfigureAwait(false);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Report(e);
                throw;
            }
        }

        static void OnHttpRequestFailed(string message) => HttpRequestFailed?.Invoke(null, message);

        static void Report(Exception e, [CallerMemberName]string callerMemberName = "") => Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried removing the using statement (which handles the dispose) and I still get the exception.

Comment: You should get a different exception if you're not disposing of HttpClient, and these are fine. This is just HttpClient letting you know that the connection failed, which it should because your server is disabled. The exception you get should be a System.Net.WebException, a Java.Net.ConnectException, a Java.Net.ConnectException, or a Java.IO.IOException, depending on the state of your server.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (it worked fine in UWP but this error on Android).
Please see this linked question for what fixed it for me: [HttpClient.SendAsync throws ObjectDisposedException on Xamarin.Forms Android but not on UWP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59933234/httpclient-sendasync-throws-objectdisposedexception-on-xamarin-forms-android-but?noredirect=1#comment105991407_59933234)