# HttpClient.SendAsync throws ObjectDisposedException on Xamarin.Forms Android but not on UWP

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, dotnet-httpclient

I'm writing a Xamarin.Forms application and I'm trying to do a Post to my webserver with some JSON payload.

This works fine in UWP, but on Android I get the following error:

```
 System.ObjectDisposedException: Can not access a closed Stream.
  at System.IO.StreamHelpers.ValidateCopyToArgs (System.IO.Stream source, System.IO.Stream destination, System.Int32 bufferSize) [0x0003a] in <19853c43ab794d18ab1a33ecb65b3c4d>:0 
  at System.IO.MemoryStream.CopyToAsync (System.IO.Stream destination, System.Int32 bufferSize, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00000] in <19853c43ab794d18ab1a33ecb65b3c4d>:0 
  at Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler.WriteRequestContentToOutput (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, Java.Net.HttpURLConnection httpConnection, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x0009a] in <2bd1b8f6e97f44bbb32ce356b78d4ce6>:0 
  at Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler.DoProcessRequest (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, Java.Net.URL javaUrl, Java.Net.HttpURLConnection httpConnection, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken, Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler+RequestRedirectionState redirectState) [0x002f4] in <2bd1b8f6e97f44bbb32ce356b78d4ce6>:0 
  at Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler.SendAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x002cf] in <2bd1b8f6e97f44bbb32ce356b78d4ce6>:0 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] sendTask, System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource cts, System.Boolean disposeCts) [0x0017e] in <c85119bf7e3e421490ae6b5487992fff>:0 
  at BB.App.Services.WebserviceHelper.PostToWebservice[T] (System.String url, System.String json) [0x0008d] in C:\_Sources\_BB\BB.App\BB.App\Services\WebserviceHelper.cs:74
```

This happens when the following code is executed:

```
await httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequest);
```

I found [this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50991291/httpclient-objectdisposedexception-android) where it recommends not putting the creation of the HttpClient in a using statement, I changed this but it didn't fix my problem.

I also found [this bug](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/1282) that is supposed to be fixed last year. To be honest this sounds like the most likely candidate but I don't know exactly what to update to get this fix on my pc. I already updated all my xamarin.android.x references in my solution but no luck so far.

Comment: which [HttpClient have you specified in Android project properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/http-stack?tabs=windows)?

Comment: @magicandre1981 I don't know what you mean, under "application" I have selected compile using android version 8.1 (oreo). Under "android manifest" I have selected Android 5.0 (api level 27 lollipop) for minimum android version, and for target android version I have selected Android 8.1

Comment: Ah, now I see you posted a link. Hmm.. the recommended setting of 'Android' was active. When I changed it to 'Managed' my problem went away. Thank you very much!

Comment: which Android version do you use on the device with the crash and which API version does your project target? normally you should use the AndroidClientHandler

Comment: Don't dispose of HttpClient. It is designed to be reused and handle multiple simultaneous requests. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50991291/httpclient-objectdisposedexception-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in conclusion what fixed my problem was to

- going to the properties of the android project,
- selecting the 'android options' tab,
- clicking 'advanced'
- setting the 'httpclient implementation' from 'Android' to 'Managed'

Comment: A lot has changed but the problem in the .NET MAUI 7 remains the same (unfortunately). I am using Semantic Kernel SDK and it has the similar issue with Android. It works perfect on my Windows app. Is there a way to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

Another option (given you're not disposing HttpClient) is that your server is redirecting, e.g. http to https.

Even if the server certificate is valid, HttpClient throws a `ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed Stream.` exception when trying to `SendAsync`.

If you can, the solution is to "fix" the redirect, e.g. for a .NET Core development web server, don't call `UseHttpsRedirection()`.

Comment: This was the correct solution for me, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For those still struggling and barely even finding this thread. If the accepted answer doesn't work for you, try setting disposeHandler = false; as in new HttpClient(handler, false); as in

```
        public AppState()
    {
        HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
        handler.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        http = new HttpClient(handler, false) { BaseAddress = new Uri("url") };
    }
```