# 2nd Android HttpClient POST throws System.ObjectDisposedException before it's ever used

Tags: c#, android, maui, .net-7.0

I'm building a .NET 7 MAUI app for Windows/Android that just makes API requests and displays that data. It starts by making 3 POST requests to gain access keys, with each one being a separate `HttpClient` as they are different URIs. The first works fine, but any subsequent request keeps throwing `System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed Stream`. This is directly after creating the client and trying to send the POST. I'm not using any `using` statements, so I'm not sure how it could possibly be disposed of. Everything works on Windows, but not on my Android device or emulator.

Here's my code simplified to just this client:

```
HttpClient client = new();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://prod.trackmania.core.nadeo.online/");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", token);
StringContent content = new("", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
HttpResponseMessage resp = await client.PostAsync("v2/authentication/token/ubiservices", content);
```

It seems only a couple people have ever had this problem, and the go-to solution is to instantiate the client with the `AndroidMessageHandler`. I also tried this with `disposeHandler` set to `false`, but no change with either option:

```
// disposeHandler true (default)
HttpClient client = new(new Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidMessageHandler());

// disposeHandler false
HttpClient client = new(new Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidMessageHandler(), false);
```

If I breakpoint just before making the request, I can see the client's `_disposed` value is `false`.

Adding `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` to my AndroidManifest.xml changes nothing.

I can't change my "HttpClient Implementation" as it's not anywhere in my project settings. Maybe that was only an option before MAUI, I can't tell.

What could possibly be going on here? I'm not manually disposing of anything, so something about Android is doing that for me and I can't figure out how to disable that.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Yes, I'm making one client, using it, and it works. Then creating another client, and that second one thinks it's disposed, even though it has not yet been used. My title states that. The only Xamarin answer I've come across is here, which does not seem to apply anymore: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59933234/httpclient-sendasync-throws-objectdisposedexception-on-xamarin-forms-android-but

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved it! It turns out the `StringContent` object needs to be set before each use and I can't really see why. I've skipped that variable and am just passing a new one into the POST request like so:

```
HttpResponseMessage resp = await client.PostAsync(
    "v2/authentication/token/ubiservices",
    new StringContent("", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
);
```

Comment: It's because `StringContent` is disposable, and once you give it to the request, the request owns it, so it disposes it.